# IE not recognizing "float:left"

Tags: css, css-float, alignment, internet-explorer-7

I'm making a website, and have an wrapper at the top with two elements within it, one with a left float, and the other with a margin on the left side of it to make up for the space the floated object takes up.  This works beautifully in ALL browsers except IE.  It's as if it's recognizing the floated object as a "real" object, and forcing the other to go below it.

If you have IE, you can see at:
http://www.panache.com/books/ArtOfCelebration/ChicagoAndGreaterMidwest/

Here's the CSS, please help! Thank you!

```
#wrapper {
width: 936px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 22px;
padding-right: 22px;
padding-left: 22px;
}
#leftobject {
height: 275px;
width: 275px;
float: left;
margin-top: 101px;
border-top-width: thin;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000;
padding-top: 11px;
margin-left: 7px;
}
#rightobject {
width: 625px;
margin-left: 304px;
height: 275px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE? There are currently at least four different versions in use around the world, which did you test with?

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me it looks fine down to IE8

Comment: i think its ie7... ie8/9/10 works fine

Comment: double-margin bug ie?

Comment: In IE7 you can remove the "width" from #logo in your css

Comment: You have no '#leftobject' and '#rightobject' id's in your html.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies! After reading your comments I double checked the version I was testing on, as I was fairly certain it was IE 8. It was, but it was still "messed up" on that machine. I asked another co-worker to pull it up on her screen and it looked perfect.

After playing around we realized that in IE there is a button for "Compatibility Mode" - which was "on" on the original machine I was using to test. Once this mode was turned off, it looked perfect. I feel so dumb! Thanks everyone for your responses which led to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove width from id logo it will work for IE 7.